# Лучший способ создать n одинаковых компонентов в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Суть:**

У нас есть число `n`, которое говорит, сколько компонентов `Component` должно быть отредеренно внутри родительского блока `Parent`. Например, если `n = 3`, то в итоге должно получиться вот так:

```
<Parent>
    <Component />
    <Component />
    <Component />
</Parent>
```

Но если компонентов больше, то вписывать их вручную не очень хочется.

**Как решаю проблему сейчас?**

Создаю массив c `n` пустыми значениями и заполняю их нулями, например, чтобы можно было применить метод `map`. Затем, собственно делаю из нулей компоненты:

```
<Parent>
    {Array(n).fill(0).map( (item, index) => <Component key={index} /> )}
</Parent>
```

Работает прекрасно - выглядит ужасно и нечетабельно. Я не заполняю массив напрямую нужным компонентом т.к. в этом случае мне не удастся передать `key`.

**Вопрос:**

Как также просто (в одну строчку), но более изящно и понятно для других, сделать тоже самое?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-repeat-component

Comment: @АндрейNOP пожалуй, лучший вариант

Comment: Ну да, почему бы просто не вынести в отдельный компонент и потом пользоваться им при необходимости :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Parent>
    { [...Array(n)].map((item, index) => <Component key={index} /> ) }
</Parent>
```

мой вариант. и оператор `spread (троеточие)` здесь наобходим, так как просто `Array(n)` создаст массив со свойством `length: n`, но без ключей, потому метод `map` не сработает